# Windows 7 Task manager doesn't show process memory usage data in the working set columns!

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

An issue with Windows 7 Task Manager. In the Processes tab 2 columns related to process usage memory ('working set' and 'private working set') are shown but with no data! In the Resource Monitor in the Performance tab they are shown instead!

does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can select a number of measures to include in the Processes tab: View | Select Columns….

However, without a fair understanding of Windows virtual and physical address space and memory management system *all* the numbers should be treated as a poor guide.

(To learn more of the complexities—difference between shared and non-shared, address space and commit, work set vs. virtual address space, ...—Mark Russinovich's two part presentation at [PDC10](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/) is a pretty good introduction.)

Comment: Thank you Richard!

Actually I can see the columns but not the numbers!

Here is a snapshot:
http://i54.tinypic.com/e5qpl4.jpg

Comment: @user68115: Suggest having a look at [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653), if that has the same problem (when run as administrator) ⇒ you have a significant problem with your system. If Process Explorer is OK, not sure why there would be this inconsistency (but can't think it is a good sign).

Comment: followed your suggestion.. but numbers are shown neither in Process Explorer! I can see them only In Resource Monitor!

What is the next step ?!

Comment: @Baky: I'm really not sure, they've always worked here. So 1. refine Q here, 2. Google/Bing for others with the same problem, use this information to help with #1. And make sure any important data is backed up (and verify it is recoverable), you might be looking at a repair or re-install.

Comment: Are you running Task Manager or Process Explorer as Administrator?  I've seen that behavior when running as a standard user, but not as admin.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you start in Safe Mode or log in as a different user?

---

This talks about the {user name} column being blank, being caused by the Terminal Services service not running.  (Saw nothing about a {memory} column being blank.)

http://www.winxptutor.com/tmuserblank.htm

Comment: @therube: thanks! the issue does not persist when I log in as a different user! The Terminal Services (Remote Desktop Services) is already set to automatic and is running for every user!